# If sufficienly many people are born, then is it possible that two persons are genetically identical although they are not twins?

Tags: dna, human-genome

It is my tought experiment.

Since for human, the genome information is finite, if so many many people are born,
then there exist two people who have the same genome although they are not a twin.

Is it true?

And how many people need that this event happens?

Comment: 3 x 10^614 which is a ridiculously large number. in the time needed to get that many humans the human genome will change enough to make it impossible because the species will have changed, humans would also have to have colonized many many planets. .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a very crude level, the [full human genome contains 6 billion nucleotide pairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Human_genome). Each of those nucleotide pairs has four possible values: AT, GC, TA, and CG. That means there are $4^{6e9}$ (4^(6 X 10^9)) possible human genomes. This is very crude. Not all human genomes are exactly the same size, some combinations would be phenotypically indistinguishable, and some would not be compatible with life. [This crude number is larger than the number of atoms thought to exist in the universe](https://www.ck12.org/flexi/earth-science/atoms-and-molecules/how-many-atoms-exist-in-the-universe/#:%7E:text=The%20universe%20is%20a%20vast,atoms%20in%20the%20known%20universe.). This means you'd never be able to have all those people exist at the same time. The human genome is finite, but so is the amount of matter in the universe.

Comment: Wouldn't you only have to compare the SNPs rather than the whole genome? It's still a big number but less than 6 billion.

Comment: I find this number way too crude. You've given the number of unique nucleotide sequences that are 6 billion base pairs long, but only a tiny vanishing minority of those could reasonably be called a "human genome". The odds of two identical genomes spontaneously arising is nigh impossible, but this takes it too far - *virtually all* of the sequences you're counting here could never be observed in a human.

Comment: There are ~600 million SNPs, so only one order of magnitude off from the crude level; still well beyond reality.  Admittedly, most of those are unlikely.  Fine.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4750478/ found "that a typical genome differs from the reference human genome at 4.1 million to 5.0 million sites."  4^(4000000) is still beyond any reference.  Indeed, if there are 10^80 atoms, that's equal to roughly 4^133, so you don't need much at all.

Comment: My suggest was absolutely an incredibly crude estimate. As @NuclearHoagie rightly point out virtually none of the random 6 billion pair sequences would be a functional human genome. On the other hand just counting SNP would be a massive undercount since by definition a SNP occurs in at least 1% of the population. There are  a lot single base pair mutations floating around transiently that never establish themselves as a SNP. And we aren't even considering things like repeat expansion, monosomies and trisomies. I think we all agree that the number of possible, viable human genomes is huge.